# Routing a get request to a module controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I what to route a request

```
/cart
```

to a controller in a module

```
Customer::CartController
```

after looking in the rails documentation the line of code in the routes.rb should be

```
get "cart" => "cart#index", :module => "customer", :as => :cart
```

but for some reason is not working. It keeps showing `uninitialized constant CartController`

Any idea how can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:module => 'customer'` should go to the scope call:

```
scope :module => "customer" do
  get "cart" => "cart#index", :as => :cart
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
get "cart" => "customer/cart#index", :as => :cart
```